# SaltStack disable local windows Administrator if it is enabled

Tags: salt-stack

I'd like to disable the built-in windows local administrator account if it is enabled.

As [salt.state.user.present](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.user.html) doesn't support disabling accounts, I'm using [salt.modules.win_useradd.update](https://ansible-cn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.win_useradd.html#salt.modules.win_useradd.update). However, it disables the account even if it is already disabled.

I can't use [`unless`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html#unless) or [`onlyif`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html#onlyif) because they only use results parsed from shell commands.

Is there a way to use the boolean value for `[user.info][account_disabled]` in [salt.module.win_useradd.info](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.win_useradd.html#salt.modules.win_useradd.info)'s [return data](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/writing.html#return-data) 'changes' dictionary as a requirement?

I'd like to do something like the following:

```
builtin_administrator:
  module.run:
    - user.info:
      - name: Administrator

disable_builtin_administrator:
  module.run:
    - user.update:
      - name: Administrator
      - account_disabled: true
    - require:
      - module: builtin_administrator
    - require:
      - module: builtin_administrator['changes']['user.info']['account_disabled']['false']
```

You can see the results data changes dictionary from [win_useradd.info](https://ansible-cn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.win_useradd.html#salt.modules.win_useradd.info) in the output:

```
local:
----------
          ID: builtin_administrator
    Function: module.run
      Result: True
     Comment: user.info: Built-in account for administering the computer/domain
     Started: 15:59:56.440000
    Duration: 15.0 ms
     Changes:
              ----------
              user.info:
                  ----------
                  account_disabled:
                      True
                  account_locked:
                      False
                  active:
                      False
                  comment:
                      Built-in account for administering the computer/domain
                  description:
                      Built-in account for administering the computer/domain
                  disallow_change_password:
                      False
                  expiration_date:
                      2106-02-07 01:28:15
                  expired:
                      False
                  failed_logon_attempts:
                      0L
                  fullname:
                  gid:
                  groups:
                      - Administrators
                  home:
                      None
                  homedrive:
                  last_logon:
                      Never
                  logonscript:
                  name:
                      Administrator
                  passwd:
                      None
                  password_changed:
                      2019-10-09 09:22:00
                  password_never_expires:
                      True
                  profile:
                      None
                  successful_logon_attempts:
                      0L
                  uid:
                      S-1-5-21-3258603230-662395079-3947342588-500
----------
          ID: disable_builtin_administrator
    Function: module.run
      Result: False
     Comment: The following requisites were not found:
                                 require:
                                     module: builtin_administrator['changes']['user.info']['account_disabled']['false']
     Started: 15:59:56.455000
    Duration: 0.0 ms
     Changes:

Summary for local
------------
Succeeded: 1 (changed=1)
Failed:    1
------------
Total states run:     2
Total run time:  15.000 ms
```

I'm testing with a Windows 10 1903 masterless salt-minion 2019.2.1 (Fluorine) where I set `use_superseded` for [module.run](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.module.html) in the minion config file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I settled for this:

```
localuser.disable.administrator:
  cmd.run:
    - name: "Get-LocalUser Administrator | Disable-LocalUser"
    - shell: powershell
    - onlyif: powershell -command "if ((Get-LocalUser | Where-Object {($_.Name -eq 'Administrator') -and ($_.Enabled -eq $true)}) -eq $null) {exit 1}"
```